# JavaScript sort array by index in a vertical way

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have this array:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

I get the number of the columns to display it from the server, for this example I chose 3.

So far I have this function that works fine except if my index is equal to the array length something goes wrong in the order and I don't know how to fix it.

```
var i;
var j;
var columns = window.columns; //3 for the example.
var lettersArray= ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var rows = Math.ceil(lettersArray.length/columns);
```

So far I have this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                     for (j=0; j < lettersArray.length; j=j+rows)  
                     {

                        var index = i+j;
                        if (index>=lettersArray.length)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          PrintArray(lettersArray, index); 
                        }   
                     }
            }
```

The PrintArray function receive the index and the array after the sorting and it suppose to look like this in the end:

```
A J S 
B K T 
C L U 
D M V
E N W
F O X
G P Y 
H Q Z 
I R
```

But somewhere in the way something goes wrong and it looks like:

```
A J S 
B K T 
C L U 
D M V
I N W
F O X
G P Y 
H Q R 
E Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're saying is you want to iterate through each item by `row + col * rows`. You also must not stop on *undefined* because you may still have more rows to go.

Here is an example of how you might do that,

```
function foo(data, cols) {
    var rows = Math.ceil(data.length / cols);
    var col, row;
    for (row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
        for (col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
            console.log(data[row + col * rows] || '');
}
```

Where `console.log` is logging the next item or `||` an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses actual sorting.

```js
var alphabet = [];
var i = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
var j = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);
for (; i <= j; i++)
  alphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(i));

function alphabetIndex(c) {
  return c.charCodeAt(0) - 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
}

var rowSize = 3; // AKA numCols; Retrieved from server.
var colSize = Math.ceil(alphabet.length / rowSize);
function sortKey(c) {
  return (rowSize * (alphabetIndex(c) % colSize)) +
         Math.floor(alphabetIndex(c) / colSize);
}

alphabet.sort(function(a, b) {
  return sortKey(a) - sortKey(b);
});

for (i = 0, j = alphabet.length; i < j; i += rowSize)
  console.log(alphabet.slice(i, i + rowSize).join(' '));
```